# Excel new data type

Tags: excel, vba, types

I have, for example, two values, each are represented by a mean and a standard deviation. Right now first one is in cell A1 and A2 and second one is in cell A4 and A5, representing the mean and stddev for each one. 
I will calculate in column B and C each one using :

```
=NORM.INV(RAND();$A$1;$A$2)
=NORM.INV(RAND();$A$4;$A$5)
```

Now in column D I will do some operation with both terms and in E1 I will get the mean of all points in column D, and E2 the stddev of all points in column D.

I want to encapsulate everything using vba but I would prefer having mean and stddev, which are two doubles in a single cell.

How do I create this data type that supports two numbers - Ideally I would like to read it like (mean,stddev) .

Example cell A1 is (21.0,3.2),how do I get each value from a function that has A1 as input?

Comment: I just have to ask. *Why* do you want to put two separate pieces of data into one cell? Certainly, what you want can be done, but I need to know *why* before offering advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function

```
Function ToArray(ByVal rng As Range, Optional ByVal sDelimit As String = ",") As Double()
Dim sNumbers() As String
Dim dNumbers() As Double, i As Integer

sNumbers = Split(rng, sDelimit)
ReDim Preserve dNumbers(UBound(sNumbers))
For i = LBound(sNumbers()) To UBound(sNumbers())
    dNumbers(i) = CDbl(sNumbers(i))
Next

ToArray = dNumbers

End Function
```

You'll be able to use it in Excel sheet:

```
=NORM.INV(RAND();ToArray($A$1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class [like this](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/classes):

> A class is created just like a module. By default it will create a
>   module called 'Class1'. First job is to go to the properties tab and
>   rename it to something sensible. The 'standard' naming convention is
>   clsYourClassName, however I personally use c prefix rather than cls.
>   This class module is your vba class constructor.

This class has two properties:

```
Option Explicit

Private dMean As Double
Private dStddev As Double

Public Property Get Mean() As Double
    Mean = dMean 
End Property

Public Property Let Mean(p As Double)
    dMean = p
End Property

Public Property Get Stddev() As Double
    Stddev = dStddev 
End Property

Public Property Let Stddev(p As Double)
    dStddev = p
End Property

Public Sub Assign(a As Double, b As Double)
    Mean = a
    Stddev = b
End Sub
```

Then you need to instantiate your class and assign a value.

I assume that the value of `Cells(1, 1).Value` is something like `(21.0,3.2)`:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim mc As cMyClass
    Set mc = New cMyClass()
    mc.Assign(Cells(1, 1).Value)
    ' do things

    Set mc = Nothing
End Sub
```

[EDIT]

As I wrote, I assume that the value of Cells(1, 1).Value is something like (21.0,3.2). If not and only one string will be returned, we need to parse it like e.g. :

```
Public Sub Assign(str As String)
    Dim ar() As String = Split(str, ",")
    If UBound(ar) = 2 Then
      Mean = CDbl(ar(0))
      Stddev = CDbl(ar(1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the signature of `Assign` Sub expects 2 parameters while you seem to be passing only one argument to it: `Cells(1, 1).Value`. Isn't there something wrong with that?